# How to save and load a div structure with cookies in query

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I have a page that allows you to remove "alert" divs by clicking a close button. I am trying to save the state of the alert window so when the page is refreshed, the closed alerts stay closed.
The div structure of the alert window looks like this.

```
 <div class="alertwindow"> 
  <div class="alerts">
      <div class="alert">
        <div class="alert_title"> Title 1</div>
        <div class="alert_desc"> Description here </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is the script to add the close button and the function to remove the alert.

```
  //Close alert window button
$(".alert").prepend('<div class="closeAlerts">X</div>');

$('.closeAlerts').on('click', function(){
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

This is all working fine, but I can't get the cookie to save and replace the content of .alertwindow.
Here is my cookie code.

```
//Check for alert cookie and reset alert state if it is there
$( window ).load(function(e) {
    if ($.cookie("alertState") == ""){
    $.cookie("alertState", $('.alertwindow').html(), 10);
    }
    else {
        $('.alertwindow').html().replaceWith($.cookie("alertState"));
    }
});

//set Alert cookie on page unload
$( window ).unload(function(e) {
    $.cookie("alertState", $('.alertwindow').html(), 10);
});
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
else {
    $('.alertwindow').html($.cookie("alertState"));
}
```

Comment: The alerts still return when I refresh the page. Am I not saving the div structure into the cookie properly?